# Parse JSON from Raw format to CSV for a total novice

Tags: json, csv, parsing

I'm looking for a way to parse RAW JSON into CSV and I'm a total novice with anything related to coding, programming, etc. I've found a site https://json-csv.com/ that does exactly what I need but the data sets I'm parsing are bigger than their free amount so I basically pay $10 a month for something I believe could be done by way of macro or something I could figure out.

I'm essentially looking for a quick way to parse this below chunk into a structured, column based detail. The columns would be: Key, Value, Context_Geography, Context_CompanyID, Context_ProductID, Description, Created by, Updated by, updated date.

{"policies":[{"key":"viaPayEnabledRates","value":"","context":{"geography":"*","companyID":"*","productID":"*"},"created_by":"0","updated_by":"0","updated_date":"2014-03-24T21:22:25.420+0000"},{"key":"viaPayEnabledRates","value":"[\"WSPNConsortia\",\"WSPNNegotiated\",\"WSPNPublished\"]","context":{"geography":"*","companyID":"*","productID":"60003"},"description":"Central Payment Pilot","created_by":"10130590","updated_by":"10130590","updated_date":"2016-04-05T07:51:29.043+0000"}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

If the file `filter.jq` contains

```
def headers:
  [
    "Key", "Value", "Context_Geography", "Context_CompanyID", "Context_ProductID",
    "Description", "Created by", "Updated by", "updated date"
  ]
;

def fields:
  [
    .key, .value, .context.geography, .context.companyID, .context.productID,
    .description, .created_by, .updated_by, .updated_date
  ]
;

  headers, (.policies[] | fields)
| @csv
```

and the file `data.jq` contains your sample data

```
 {
  "policies": [
    {
      "key": "viaPayEnabledRates",
      "value": "",
      "context": {
        "geography": "",
        "companyID": "",
        "productID": ""
      },
      "created_by": "0",
      "updated_by": "0",
      "updated_date": "2014-03-24T21:22:25.420+0000"
    },
    {
      "key": "viaPayEnabledRates",
      "value": "[\"WSPNConsortia\",\"WSPNNegotiated\",\"WSPNPublished\"]",
      "context": {
        "geography": "",
        "companyID": "*",
        "productID": "60003"
      },
      "description": "Central Payment Pilot",
      "created_by": "10130590",
      "updated_by": "10130590",
      "updated_date": "2016-04-05T07:51:29.043+0000"
    }
  ]
}
```

then running jq as

```
jq -M -r -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces the output

```
"Key","Value","Context_Geography","Context_CompanyID","Context_ProductID","Description","Created by","Updated by","updated date"
"viaPayEnabledRates","","","","",,"0","0","2014-03-24T21:22:25.420+0000"
"viaPayEnabledRates","[""WSPNConsortia"",""WSPNNegotiated"",""WSPNPublished""]","","*","60003","Central Payment Pilot","10130590","10130590","2016-04-05T07:51:29.043+0000"
```